# how to set publisher name on exe in c#

Tags: c#, vsto

I need to add the publisher name when the exe installs. I have tried the following links from blogs, but it is still not working.

[Reference1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-specify-advanced-publishing-options-saurabh-bhatia.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

[Reference2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2008/06/11/specify-a-product-name-publisher-name-and-other-properties-for-vsto-solutions-saurabh-bhatia.aspx?CommentPosted=true&PageIndex=2#comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so when you create an installer, but not when the application is installed. Do you use a valid certificate from a trusted authority?

The [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) section in MSDN describes all the required steps for creating add-in installers.

Comment: no i am not familiar with that certificate. Could you please provide me any link for that and how to implement certificate to set publisher name